# Read existing gurobi .lp-file and add constraints to it

Tags: python, gurobi

I have a little problem using Gurobi in Python. I have a .lp-file, where my linear programm is saved. To these constraints I want to add some additional constraints. Loading and optimizing works without any problems, but I just cannot add new constraints to my model. I do not know what I am doing wrong...
I hope there is someone, who finds my mistake!
Thanks!

My code looks like below (I made it a bit easier)
SI is a two-dimensional array containing the data for every variable.

`from gurobipy import *
model = read("testdatei.lp")
for j in range(len(SI)):
    model.addConstr(x[SI[j][0], SI[j][1], SI[j][2], SI[j][3], SI[j][4], SI[j][5]] == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your error message, I assume the problem is that you have not defined `x`.
The quickest way to fix this would probably be to reconstruct the variable name (that you defined earlier when building the model) from the `SI` values and then  access the variables with `getVarByName`.

If this is slow because the model is big and you are accessing many variables, you could instead get the array of all variables with `model.getVars()`, then iterate over this and rebuild your multi-dimensional array (or `tuple_dict`) `x` by parsing the names of the variables.